# I don't know why I'm getting "0" at index 13 of temp

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to rearrange *ini* string into `temp`, outer loop is for number of characters in `temp` and inner loop is to find the index number from `PC2_table` and append the character `ini[j]` to `temp`, everything is working fine but I don't know why I'm getting nothing at index 13.

```
string ini = "000100010000110011110100001001101001001110101101";
Console.WriteLine(ini.Length + " " +ini[0]);            
int[] PC2_table = { 13 ,   16 ,  10 ,   23 ,    0,    4,
                     2 ,   27 ,  14 ,    5 ,   20,    9,
                    22 ,   18 ,  11 ,    3 ,   25,    7,
                    15 ,    6 ,  26 ,   19 ,   12,    1,
                    40 ,   51 ,  30 ,   36 ,   46,   54,
                    29 ,   39 ,  50 ,   44 ,   32,   47,
                    43 ,   48 ,  38 ,   55 ,   33,   52,
                    45 ,   41 ,  49 ,   35 ,   28,   31};

ini = " " + ini;   // because PC2 table main indexing 1 sy hai
string temp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < PC2_table.Length; j++)
    {                    
     if(PC2_table[j] == i)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(i + " " +j + " " + ini[j] );
         temp += ini[j];
         break;
     }                 
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic

Comment: Remove `ini = " " + ini;`. `PC2_table` has a zero in it. Why do you think index starts at `1`?

Answer (score 2):

At `i = 13`, when `j = 0`, what happen is:

```
PC2_table[j] = PC2_table[0] = 13
```

and `i` is `13`, thus you enter the `if` block:

```
if(PC2_table[j] == i){ //enters
}
```

But:

```
ini[j] = ini[0] = " ";
```

Is a `space` due to:

```
string ini = "000100010000110011110100001001101001001110101101";
...
ini = " " + ini; //note the addition of " " in front of original ini
```

Note that now, `ini` is:

```
" 000100010000110011110100001001101001001110101101" //the first element at index [0] is " "
```

And you do:

```
temp += ini[j]; //"1000001100110" + " " = "1000001100110 " //additional space
```

Thus you got your space added in your 13-th index:

Comment: @JohnMaxwell yep, be careful. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the statement

`ini = " " + ini;`

So your first char in ini is empty.
Then you have the combination of i = 13 and j = 0, where the program is trying to access position 0 of ini, so he's returning your empty space.
So you should probably fix your indexes.

Regardless of the fact that i have no freakin' idea what this program is doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You get 0 at index 13, because `PC2_table[0]` is 13 and in this case `j` equals `0`.